# Sorting by relevance of the search phrase by the value in the field in Solr

Tags: search, solr

Version of Solr core 8.10.1
I have a schema with fields: name, price.
For example, in Solr is docs exist records:
[
{
"name":"Кабель питания сист.блок-монитор Gembird 4.5-5.0м, черный, с зазем., пакет [PC-189-15]",
"price_currency":2.09
},
{
"name":"Монитор 15' LG 1510 TFT",
"price_currency":0.0
}
]

I need to sort the result by relevance field (asc) and price (desc). How to correctly compose an expression in the sort field?
In case when I write: sort=price desc, in result the first record is higher than the second, and I need the opposite.
My incorrect query example:
http://localhost/solr/#/catalog/query?q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%0A15&q.op=AND&indent=true&sort=price%20asc&df=text&rows=100

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like this: score asc, price desc in the sort field.
Here is the documentation: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/common-query-parameters.html#sort-parameter
This is the relevant info from the documentation (an example)

"inStock desc, price asc
Sorts by the contents of the inStock field in descending order, then when multiple documents have the same value for the inStock field, those results are sorted in ascending order by the contents of the price field."